# Manipulate Service member variables by new Thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a service and a method in it that manipulates member variables and its work is heavy. I want to manipulate service member variables by new thread, but when i do that the application gets "Android Not Responding". How can i do that in new thread or Runnable?
my new thread is in service(created in service and manipulate service variables)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) it starts the thread for you.You will need to override [onHandleIntent](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)) with your logic.